# Proving that if $a^2+b^2=c^2$, then $a+b\ge c$.

Tags: real-analysis

Hello, I'm trying to prove this statement.

> Let a,b & c be three positive real numbers and if $a^2+b^2=c^2$ then $a+b\ge c$

Any help, please?

Comment: For a geometric method, what theorem does $a^2+b^2=c^2$ remind you of?

Comment: For an algebraic method, how can you get something close to $a^2+b^2$ from $a+b$?

Comment: And for *positive* real numbers, euclidean geometry gives sharp inequality, not only a weak one.

Comment: @MarkS.Yes the Pythagorean theorem, how could have I missed it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$(a+b)^2=a^2+b^2+2ab\geq a^2+b^2= c^2\rightarrow (a+b)^2\geq c^2\rightarrow a+b\geq c$

Answer (score 5):

Hints:

(1) If for positive real numbers $\;a,b,c\;$ we have that $\;a^2+b^2=c^2\;$ , then there exists a right triangle with legs $\;a,b\;$ and hypotenuse $\;c\;$

(2) In Euclidean Geometry : the sum of the lengths of **any** two sides of **any** triangle is greater than the length of the third side.

Comment: (2) is obviously wrong.  Replace “greater than” by “not more than”, please.

Comment: Not at all, @Michael. Give a counterexample or apologize and delete your comment, "please"....because, for example, I can provide proofs for my statement (2).

Comment: I assume DonAntonio is talking about triangles with area. =). Also known as non-degenerate triangles or triangles. It's not a big deal really

Comment: I'm talking of **euclidean** triangles, as written there: or course, with area. Non-euclidean geometries can yield lots of funny results, though.

Comment: @DonAntonio If you don't mind, I'll vote for the first of your options.  Consider the triangle $(0,0)$, $(1,1)$, $(2,2)$.

Comment: Your vote (choice), just like your attitude, is wrong, @MichaelHoppe: your example yields no **euclidean** triangle at all, and not only because you try to resource to *analytic geometry*...

Comment: @user4140 I agree; yet the triangle inequality becomes an equality iff the triangle is degenerated, which is used in several proves.

Comment: @MichaelHoppe, you seem to willingly choose not to read what you're said, and this can't be a good habit for anyone minimally interested in *learning*: there are no "degenerated" triangles in **euclidean geometry** .

Comment: This is getting too personal.  I'll answer after I'll get some sleep.  There's an old Usenet wisdom: “Don't post if you're angry, drunk, or stoned.”

Comment: The OP is not about triangles at all, so this debate is moot

Comment: @MichaelHoppe I think you and DonAntonio are following different conventions, and that if DonAntonio added "non-degenerate" to point (2), then it would fix things for your convention and not change things for DonAntonio's. I happen to prefer DonAntonio's convention (which is shared by the wikipedia page for Triangle), but would not object to the addition of "non-degenerate" and think it's a little silly (for either of you) to get worked up about a convention like this as if this is something every mathematician agrees on. (A degenerate right triangle has a side of length zero anyway.)

Comment: @MichaelHoppe This wisdom is hardly ever followed (or the "or" is usually interpreted as "xor")

Comment: I don't agree neither with Hagen nor with Mark and, paradoxically, I do agree with Michale's last statement and I applaud it. Hagen, it doesn't matter whether the OP is about triangles or not: either my statement is accurate or it isn't, and my answer proves, I believe, the OP's question. Mark, it's not about "conventions", as in many other parts of mathematics, but about *definitions*.

Comment: @DonAntonio Not everyone follows the convention for the definition of "triangle" in Euclidean geometry you've alluded to. For a couple examples, see the results of [this Google search](https://www.google.com/search?q="a+triangle+is+said+to+be+degenerate"). (And for another example, see Michael Hoppe.)

Comment: Thankx @MarkS. I couldn't find in any of those links the fact they're using the definition from **euclidean geometry** .Furthermore, the euclidean theorem I mention in (2) is proposition 20, Book I in Euclid's Elements .

Comment: @DonAntonio Thank you for that comment; I now understand my confusion. You've been making claims about "Euclidean Geometry", as in (roughly) "Geometry as explained by Euclid", where I was misinterpreting you as saying something more like "geometry in Euclidean space" or "Geometry like Euclidean Geometry as opposed to hyperbolic or some other nonstandard setting". [Wikipedia backs you up on this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_geometry) and it seems I was just ignorant of how specialized the phrase is, in the absence of other context. In short: You were right and I was wrong.

Comment: Thanks for that clearing, @Mark. Yes, all the time it was about Euclidean Geometry, as written in the answer. Whenever we enter non-euclidean stuff mayhem may happen, and it is in this case that a weak inequality in the OP's post can happen indeed.

Answer (score 3):

$ a  =\! \sqrt{c^2\!-b^2} =\! \sqrt{{(c\!-\!b)(c\!+\!b)}}\, >\, c\!-\!b\,\ $  by $\,\ c\!-\!b < c\!+\!b$

Answer (score 2):

*Hint:* Add $2ab$ and see what gives.

Answer (score 1):

Consider $(a+b)^2=a^2+2ab+b^2=c^2+2ab$

Since $2ab>0$ as $a,b>0$, we have

$$(a+b)^2 > c^2$$

Square rooting both sides gives the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

HINT: Consider $a,b,c$ as sides of a right triangle.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose Not, which means that $a + b < c $

Square both sides

$(a + b)^2 < c^2 $

$a^2 + b^2 + 2ab < c^2 $

But by assumption $a^2 + b^2 = c^2$

Therefore,

$a^2 + b^2 + 2ab < a^2 + b^2 $

Which means

$2ab < 0 $ where a & b are positive numbers

Contradiction as no 2 positive multiplication is less than 0

therefore,

$a+b≥c $